# How to update/modify a deployed static ReactJS site in Google cloud platform?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I have followed steps in [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509) tutorial and successfully deployed a ReactJS site. question is, how to modify or update the site with a new build/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying from the Cloud Shell the procedure is the same.

You will modify locally your code, then you will [upload it to Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files) either by uploading it to the bucket and then moving it to the Cloud Shell instance by using the `gsutil rsync -r gs://your_bucket` as described in the tutorial that you mentioned or uploading it directly to the Cloud Shell and then you can deploy again the code with the `gcloud app deploy` command. This will replace the old version of your application with the newer one.

I recommend you to take a look into the [official App Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on)

If you have more doubts let us know!

Comment: Thanks! tried this and it updated the site and also  thanks for the reccomendation! however there is an additional step just before "gcloud app deploy", which is "gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID" or "gcloud config unset project". I chose to set the project ID

Comment: You are completly right. The "gcloud config set project" command is required when you start a new Cloud Shell session to point the project where you want to interact.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the steps you did when you originally uploaded your website (assuming your bucket has a build folder and a `app.ymal` file:

1. Open the shell for the bucket (found within the buckets directory at the top right):
   [image]
2. Then type the command: `sutil rsync -r gs://your_bucket`
3. Then following: `gcloud app deploy`

Sadly, the changes could take a while too propagate. And there is no way of speeding it up - yet - it's all to do with your browsers cache, so if you'd like to see the updated version quicker, try using another device/browser to see.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I viewed right from my usual browser it is still not updated. while viewing it from incognito has the updated site.